# Are question bans only lifted following improvements to your questions? What other positive contributions also count?

Tags: support, post-ban

I'm currently under a question ban. Yes, it's annoying, but it's obviously my fault for being careless. I'm working on getting out of it now, and I've tried everything I can to improve my questions. However, all of my questions are either positively scored or are scored at zero, except 2 which were complained about as unclear, and one which was closed as duplicate. Obviously there's nothing I can do about the dupe, and with my downvoted questions commenters are mostly asking things I can't fix now, such as what I tried previously. I've tried making edits to both of them, carefully following the guidelines, but I got no extra upvotes from these edits.

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68884/why-cant-i-ask-questions-on-stackoverflow/68885#68885) seems to suggest that there's alternative ways to gain back privileges. I've taken the time during my ban to answer a bunch of questions, all of which have been positively received and most of them marked as answer. However, this doesn't seem to have affected my ban. Have I missed something? I've read through the ban FAQ and all related SO Meta posts, but I can't find anything objectively stating whether **positive actions on other people's posts affects your *question* ban status**.

Is this meant to be a secret? If so, that's fine, but I'm wondering if I've just missed something.

*Note: My question, while on a similar theme to the community FAQ, specifically asks about something that I feel has been omitted from there. I made sure to read it carefully before asking, but only resorted to asking a question because I felt that it did not explicitly answer my question.*

Comment: Afaik it's only improving existing questions and asking new well-received questions (you get one every six months, so make them count). I don't believe there are any other secret means to get out of a ban.

Comment: @TemaniAfif see my note.

Comment: Helló :-) Your for me visible questions look to me okay. Wait two weeks, probably it will be enough.

Comment: The system checks your question history so: your closed questions + deleted questions + downvoted questions. You can undelete your own-deleted questions, you can edit them to become upvotable/reopenable.

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0: ([1](//stackoverflow.com/q/54382391) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/54268293) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/53970020) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/53834117) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/53469739))

Comment: Seems to me  having looked at some of @Geza's questions (much favorited) and their accepted answers, that if their material is considered 'extremely poor' (to quote the canonical text on this)  then there is something wrong with the algorithm. Maybe some of them are a bit broad, but overall it's a creative, interesting, and useful body of work, surely? Sets the bar pretty high for /not/ getting banned.

Comment: @MandyShaw I understand some of the downvotes, but some of the others I'm just confused about. For instance, the one about [expanding cubic-beziers in CSS beyond four points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54382391/more-than-two-points-in-css3-transition-like-cubic-bezier). I put effort into researching it and then writing the question, it gets two downvotes with no explanation/comments, and it gets automatically closed a few months later. What am I supposed to do about that?

Comment: @Geza I can't see that question, sorry, as it seems to have been deleted.

Comment: @MandyShaw oh yeah true

Comment: Are you unbanned yet @Geza? (I have no idea how long it usually takes or what the rules are!)

Comment: @MandyShaw, no, it seems not unfortunately. It's fine, though. Thanks for your interest.